# Changing source of video not persistent (mobile website)

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, video

I want to use autoplaying videos on a mobile-only website.
So I am forced by some certain restrictions within google chrome (android app).

Then I want to programmatically change the source of the video to a different one.
(I tried two different aproaches, which both only work 50%)

**V1:
This is the html I want to change:**

```
<video id="overlayVideo" autoplay muted loop>
    <source id="overlayVideoSrc" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

This is my current code to change the source:

```
var $newVideo = $("<source>", {id: "overlayVideoSrc", "src": "index/RES/newVideo.mp4"});
$("#overlayVideoSrc").remove();
$("#overlayVideo").append($newVideo);
```

*This plays the video on both mobile, and desktop, but doesnt change the source whatsoever. The video that plays is always the one, I selected in the first place.*

**V2:
Also tried:**

```
<video id="overlayVideo" src="" autoplay muted loop></video>
```

Then I used the following:

```
$("#overlayVideo").attr("src", "index/RES/newVideo.mp4");
```

*This changes and plays the video on desktop, but doesn't on mobile (changes but no playing)*

I hope that you are able to follow, if there are any questions, please ask. I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the src attribute

```
$("#overlayVideo").attr("src", "index/RES/newVideo.mp4");
```

You need to re-load(update after every change) and play the video:

```
$("#overlayVideo").load();
$("#overlayVideo").play();
```